# How to group two kinds of columns into two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have downloaded data in a difficult format and I'm trying to make it tiddy. The dataframe has data from several samplings, and for each sampling it provides two columns, one for the year in which it was carried, and another for the number obtained.
This is a dummy dataset with the same structure:

```
df<-data.frame(s1y=c(2000,2001,2002),
               s1r=c(5,23,5),
               s2y=c(2004,2004,2003),
               s2r=c(6,2,3),
               s3y=c(2009,2008,2006),
               s3r=c(4,2,12))

   s1y s1r  s2y s2r  s3y s3r
1 2000   5 2004   6 2009   4
2 2001  23 2004   2 2008   2
3 2002   5 2003   3 2006  12
```

In the column name, the number stands for the number of the sampling, and "y" and "r" stand for year and result.
I don't really care about the sampling; I want two columns, one for the year and another one for the result, so it looks like this:

```
     y  r
1 2000  5
2 2001 23
3 2002  5
4 2004  6
5 2004  2
6 2003  3
7 2009  4
8 2008  2
9 2006 12
```

I've been trying to do this with `pivot_longer()`, but I don't know how to pivot into two long columns at the same time, and I've also tried to colapse it into one column like this

```
df%>%pivot_longer(cols=everything(),
                     names_pattern="(..)(.)",
                     names_to=c("sampling","type"),
                     values_to="result")
```

and then use `pivot_wider()`, but I haven't been able to achive the desired output.

Comment: Is the naming structure of the column names the same as you provided in the dummydata?

Comment: Very similar but not identical, they look like E05MTS and E05YOE, where E05 means that it's the sampling 05, and MTS/YOE differenciantes the result/year. I know that this change has an impact on the use of names_pattern in pivot_longer, but I shortened it for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? If your data is consistent (only `y` and `r`) then you need an `id_col` that changes every two rows.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_pattern="(..)(.)",
               names_to=c("sampling","type"),
               values_to = "result"
  ) %>%
  mutate(id_col = row_number() + row_number() %% 2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "id_col",
              names_from = "type",
              values_from = "result"
  )
```